# Open new window using Selenium in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to open new window in Firefox using the same webdriver, or any other technique.

Let's assume if I am working on one page that is www.abc.com and now I want to open another page, www.xyz.com and after opening I have to perform some action and compare some items from "abc" page in "xyz" page.

After comparison I want to switch back to the orignal page that is "abc". Here is chunk of code I'm using:

```
            IWebDriver iWebDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
            iWebDriver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
            iWebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");
            iWebDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            string winHandler = iWebDriver.CurrentWindowHandle;
            IWebDriver iiWebDriver = new FirefoxDriver();// trying this to open new window
            iiWebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.facebook.com/");
            iiWebDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            iiWebDriver.SwitchTo().Window(winHandler); // this aint swithcing back to the previously opened window
```

Comment: we wont do your work, but if you post what you tried and point out exactly where are you stuck we can try to help you to help yourself.

Comment: Is there a `iWebDriver.Navigate().Back()` or similar? That would resolve your problem without needing to open a new window.

Comment: (The downvotes are probably for the urgent begging in your question - please refrain from asking for speedy answers. Helpers here are volunteers who will reply at their leisure. If you are in a particular rush then you would be best seeking the services of a freelancer).

Comment: i need to open new window because,
1. I want to open another (2nd) URL/ site.
2. I dont want to loose previous work done on frst url.
and after im done with my work on url:2,
i need to switch back to frst url

Comment: i am new here and dont know the norms, thanks butt i will take that in mind next time.

Comment: Hey Junaid, its ok I understand you are new no worries. So when you are invoking firefox webdriver 2 times, it will create 2 threads of the browser not the windows, the window handler functions are used when you click on a link/button in the same browser which opens a new window, in that case you can switch back to your current window.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have launches two separate browsers, each controlled by their own driver. `iWebDriver` is the driver in control of the browser with the google page open, and `iiWebDriver` is the driver in control of the browser with the facebook page open. If you want to do something with the google page, use `iWebDriver`. If you want to do something with the facebook page, use `iiWebDriver`. You don't need to mess with window handles. The window handles method is for when a popup comes up on a single browser instance, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to open a new tab

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body")).SendKeys(Keys.Control + "t");
```

This will press the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> key hence new tab will get opened.